# mongodb lookup function returns an empty array result

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java

I have two mongodb collections employee and department as follows
employee collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58c4a35ac2e604024321788e"),
"id_employee" : 19,
"employee_name" : "Lene Vestergaard Hau",
"employee_address" : "Allerton",
"hours" : 279,
"id_department" : 1,
"projects" : [
    285,
    453,
    499,
    804,
    956
],
"Children" : [
    {
        "id_child" : 38,
        "child_name" : "Caroline Herschel"
    }
]
```

}

department collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58c49c48c2e669d6555aa5a7"),
"id_department" : 1,
"department_name" : "dept1",
"projects" : [
    {
        "id_project" : 285,
        "project_name" : "1project 285",
        "duration" : "211"
    },
    {
        "id_project" : 453,
        "project_name" : "1project453",
        "duration" : "214"
    },
    {
        "id_project" : 499,
        "project_name" : "1project499",
        "duration" : "224"
    },
    {
        "id_project" : 804,
        "project_name" : "1project804",
        "duration" : "217"
    }
    {
        "id_project" : 956,
        "project_name" : "1project956",
        "duration" : "217"
    }
```

]
I am trying to perform a lookup function to get all the details about the 
projects for the employee. The java code I am using :

```
coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("id_employee",19)),
        Aggregates.unwind("$projects"),
        Aggregates.lookup("department", "projects",               "projects.id_project", "lookupData")

)).forEach(printBlock);
}
```

the code above return lookupData as an empty list. Can any one help please?

Comment: There are two reasons in fact. There simply is no such field as `"department.projects.id_project"`. The path in fact is `"projects.id_project"`, however the other reason is none of the data you supply with your question actually has any such matching values anyway. It's also unclear what result you expect, since the `$lookup` result with matching data will in fact be the whole `"department"` document, and not just the matching project. So if your intent was to get the project information, there would still be a fair bit more work to do here. Your modelling could do with some revision.

Comment: It's also really unclear which framework and indeed which language you are working with. Some of the code suggests "spring-data-mongodb"? But for some reason there's a `.forEach()` in there so it almost looks like you are trying to do this in the shell or something else. So it's all really unclear.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your comment. Regarding the first reason I have used the whole path of the field starting with the collection name (department) then the array name (projects) and the field name at the end (id_project). I have also omitted the collection name but the problem was not solved. for the second reason there are matching field in the department collection but I did not copy the matching data in my question. I am using java and the java mongo driver 3.4.1

Comment: But the point is the "whole path" you are using is **incorrect**. You do not include the collection name there. Instead it is meant to to be relative to the foreign document only. If you believe there actually is something that should match you need to show that in your question instead. Edit your question to include reliable data from which other can reproduce your results. You also really need to specify the language and framework in use. There are "tags" for most things here on stackoverflow that you should use to categorize your question.